# Proof of the Frank-Wolfe theorem

Tags: optimization, reference-request, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

Does anybody know where I might find a proof for the Frank-Wolfe Theorem (stated below)?

---

**Frank-Wolfe Theorem:**
If a quadratic function $f$ is bounded below on a nonempty polyhedron (the intersection of finitely many half-spaces) $X$, then there exists $\bar{x} \in X$ such that $f(\bar{x}) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in X$, i.e. $f$ attains its infimum on $X$.

Comment: Maybe Marguerite Frank and Philip Wolfe, “An algorithm for quadratic programming,” Naval Research Logistics Quarterly 3 (1956) 95–110.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1002/nav.3800030109

Comment: @Aruralreader That could be an answer.